# How can I make a list self-arrange in an animated way based on periodic Json updates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a list of complex entities (`div`s), that are scored.
The list will be sorted based on updates from the server as the user fills out a form.

What I haven't figured out is how to animate the entities into their new positions.
I don't want to just refresh the list.

Is there a magic jQuery technique that achieves this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh yes there is. you will love [quick sand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/)

Comment: Quicksand seems nice, but the animations jump around a bit inexplicably. Do you see the same thing?

Comment: that I think is because it by default in its site demo uses a cc3 scaling which is not yet well implemented in most browsers. but if you take that option out which is very simply to do. it will be much smoother. i think there is an option on the site also to try it without that scaling parameter.